# Invalid API Credentials - CoinImp API

Tags: cryptocurrency

I've been trying to work with the CoinImp API. This is the documentation: https://www.coinimp.com/documentation/http-api#site-info . When I connect to the API link it returns "Invalid Credentials". https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/hashes . How do I add my credentials?

Some code:

```js
import requests

text = requests.get("https://www.coinimp.com/api/v2/hashes", {
  "X-API-ID": "",
  "X-API-KEY": ""
})

print(text.json())
```

gives "Invalid credentials.: 0"

Comment: This is my first question. Please help!

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code you've wrote (don't publish your actual credentials, just change them with some placeholder text) so we can help you

Comment: I did it. Please help

Comment: I don't know where are you importing `requests` from, but I'm sure you're not sending the credentials as request headers (that's different to request body/payload/data). Check that _requests_ module documentation, to see how you can add that information to the headers. I personally recommend using axios, but that's not related to the issue, I'm sure you can make it work with requests.

Comment: Sorry that I recommended axios, I thought without reading much that you were using javascript. Anyway, the answer is the same, just check you're sending the credentials as request headers.